# remove unwanted space between body and footer

Tags: html, css

Hello i am new for css and html.. I need to remove the space between body and footer. Any help ?
I want to add an image at the same lines with paragraph

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Neotic</title>

</head>

<body> 
<div>
<center><img src="{{STATIC_URL}}Neoticlogo.png" height="200" width="400"  alt="Logo"  ></center>

<center> <font face="Arial" size="14.18" color=" #587974" >Beat the markets with AI </font></center>

</div>
</br>
</br>
<div class='row' style="background: #3CB371" >
<div class="col-lg-4">

<p style=" color:#EDEDED; font-family: Arial; font-size:+9; padding-left: 90px; width:400px" align="justify"> Neotic is a trading support platform, that allows traders to test trading strategies and provides related trading recommendations leveraging artificial intelligence, without writing a single line of code.</p> 


 </br>
  <p style=" color:#EDEDED; font-family: Arial; font-size:+9; padding-left: 90px; width:400px" align="justify"> The artificial intelligence is based on a machine learning algorithm that incorporates corporate fundamentals, historical prices and financial news</p>
```

```
 <b> <p style=" color:#EDEDED; font-family: Arial; font-size:+10; padding-left: 90px; width:400px" align="justify"> We are upgrading our services and revamping our brand</p> </b>


</div>
```

```
  <div class="well">
   <center> <p class="text-muted" style="color:#EDEDED; font-family: Arial; font-size:+2" >©2017 Neotic. All rights reserved </p> </center>
</div>
</footer>


</body>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you add a JSFiddle and the css? Also, why is your code separated? It messes up a lot of stuff for those who are making fiddles because you didn't make one.

Comment: And by the way, as of HTML4 [the `<center>` tag is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center); use margin or `text-align: center;` instead.

Comment: @JamesDouglas I was able to scrape together a JSFiddle with his code... im going to post an answer but please correct me if im wrong...

Comment: @InvincibleM Sure

Comment: The `<font>` tag is also deprecated, so don't use it or `<center>`. Look into CSS

Comment: Thanks @JamesDouglas and good point j08691 ill change that in my JSFiddle.

Comment: Posted the Answer @JamesDouglas and j08691

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay. Fist of all... Please give all of your code and use up-to-date HTML5 code...

Using the poorly written code you provided, I made a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1brm974L/3/).

```
<div class="well">
   <center> <p class="text-muted" style="color:#EDEDED; font-family: Arial; font-size:+2" >©2017 Neotic. All rights reserved </p> </center>
</div>
</footer>
```

the `div` with the class `well` had a height of who knows what, so when I set the background color and the height at 20px, I came out with a result just like your picture.

**PS:** I removed the outdated center tags and added a `text-align:;` to the div style. I also fixed your `</br>` tags which were incorrect and reset them to `<br/>`. I also added missing starting elements like `<footer>` because of the `</footer>` in your code. Thanks to James and j08691 who pointed out that the `<font>` tags are also outdated. I fixed your code, but next time please check your HTML for outdated tags.

```html
<title>Neotic</title>
<body> 
<div>
<img src="{{STATIC_URL}}Neoticlogo.png" height="200" width="400"  alt="Logo" style>

<h1 style="text-align: center;">
<font face="Arial" size="14.18" color=" #587974">Beat the markets with AI </font>
</h1>

</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<div class='row' style="background: #3CB371" >
<div class="col-lg-4">
<p style=" color:#EDEDED; font-family: Arial; font-size:+9; padding-left: 90px; width:400px" align="justify"> Neotic is a trading support platform, that allows traders to test trading strategies and provides related trading recommendations leveraging artificial intelligence, without writing a single line of code.</p> 
 <br/>
  <p style=" color:#EDEDED; font-family: Arial; font-size:+9; padding-left: 90px; width:400px" align="justify"> The artificial intelligence is based on a machine learning algorithm that incorporates corporate fundamentals, historical prices and financial news</p> 
 <b> <p style=" color:#EDEDED; font-family: Arial; font-size:+10; padding-left: 90px; width:400px" align="justify"> We are upgrading our services and revamping our brand</p> </b>
</div>
<footer>
 <div style="background-color:#333; height:20px;">
 <p style="font-family: Arial; font-size:+2; text-align:center;color:#fff;" >©2017 Neotic. All rights reserved </p>
</div>
</footer>
```

Comment: This looks good, but we can't really tell, as the OP hasn't provided the right amound of code... Anyway, I will upvote.

Comment: Thanks. All the OP said was "I need to remove the space between body and footer." so i hope its correct

Comment: Thank youuu i really appreciate your help .. i am using css recently and i need to do more practice.